# RxJs Observable without next events?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, semaphore, rxjs6

How can I create an RxJs observable that only emits a `complete` event and no `next` events?

I have an observable that performs some operations which has a side effect in which it populates an in-memory cache. I would like to use this observable as a semaphore so that a second observable only starts executing when it is complete. Then a second observable can use this cache to decorate incoming data. My idea is to use [concat](http://rxmarbles.com/#concat) where the first observable only emits a `complete` event:

```
const cache = {};
const firstObservable = // fetch data to be cached
const secondObservable = // fetch other data that will be decorated with cached data

// add all next events of the first observable to the cache
const promise = firstObservable
   .forEach(
      data => {
         cache[data.key] = data;
      }
   );

// create a new observable that only emits a complete event
const waitForCache = of(promise)
   .pipe(
      // skip the first event from waitForCache (the empty promise event), 
      // since we are only interested in when the population of the cache is complete
      skip(1)
   );

// create a semaphore that waits for the complete event from the cache population 
// before dealing with the second observable
const decorated = concat(waitForCache, secondObservable)
   .pipe(
      map(
         data => {
            // decorate objects with data from cache
            return Object.assign({}, data, cache[data.key]);
         }
      ));
```

My assumption is that the problem is the `skip(1)` call.

- With the implementation above, the `waitForCache` completes too early and the cache is empty when the second observable attempts to fetch the value. Notably, the cache will be populated *after* the decoration has been made.
- When removing skip, the `waitForCache` observable will add an additional (empty) event to the `decorated` observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to re-implement my solution to subscribe to both observables and then use a [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) to discard the events from the `firstObservable` (that were added to the cache) so that only the events from the `secondObservable` are affected by the mapping function:

```
const cache = {};
const firstObservable = // fetch data to be cached
const secondObservable = // fetch other data that will be decorated with cached data

// add all next events of the first observable to the cache
const waitForCache = firstObservable
   .pipe(
      tap({
         next: data => {
            cache[data.key] = data;     
         }
      });

// use concat so the cache population is completed before dealing with the second observable
const decorated = concat(waitForCache, secondObservable)
   .pipe(
      filter(
         data => { return /* check for some specific property that is 
                             available in one observable, but not the other */ } 
      )
      map(
         data => {
            // decorate objects with data from cache
            return Object.assign({}, data, cache[data.key]);
         }
      ));
```